# AzureWarehouse database DimTeamProject table reportpath column is null

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-synapse

We as a company migrated from TFS 2013 to AzureDevops 2019 Server(On-Prem) and had to move old reports to the new report server. To do so we used a powershell script that uses /ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx web service to create folders and reports. We couldn't do it manually because we have lots of collections and projects under them.

We have realized that the projects created after the migration had problems with the reports. Reports we use include default CMMI reports and some custom ones we have created. Most of these by default uses a SQL system function called [GetProjectNodeInfoFromReportFolder] that is located in warehouse database. This function returns the project guid and project name based on the current path of the report folder. This function uses the table DimTeamProject under the warehouse database and the column 'ReportPath' to determine which report is triggered against.

The problem we have is that the newly created projects after the migration all have NULL values in this ReportPath column, which fails our reports.

I couldn't seem to find where this ReportPath column is being filled upon so I couldn't find the core of the problem.

Based on research I've tried rebuilding the warehouse database in the administration console but it doesn't change anything. I've also checked in the administration console that the Default Report Folder path is set correctly for all the collections.

I've also tried uploading reports manually on the ssrs web portal.

As a side note, when I check the project in the visual studio Team Explorer I cant see the Reports tab. I can for the older projects. So I believe there should be something wrong in the project configuration.

I appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: You need to start migrating to a different reporting solution anyway -- Azure DevOps Server 2020 is the last version to support the data warehouse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/reporting-services-reports?view=azure-devops-2020

Comment: Sure but I need to save the day :/

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by following the steps below:

1. Connect to the server that devops is installed on.
2. Open Azure Devops Server Administration Console
3. Select Application Tier > Team Project Collections
4. Select the desired collection and click 'Edit Default Folder Collection'
5. Enter the folder path on the pop up and press OK. In my case it was already set but I was still having the problem mentioned in the question. (/TfsReports/DefaultCollection)

After 2-3 minutes setting the value in the last step, the warehouse db got updated and all the null values got replaced with the correct information.

**NOTE: This process needs to be repeated after a new project is created, otherwise the newly created project will still have a null value on reportpath